# why useEffect might be called if subscribed array hadn't changed yet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a very simple app with just `useReducer()` and two `useEffect()`. Here is the full log.

[image: log]

How does it work?

1. As you can see I've marked full `useEffect()` lifecycle from *begin* to *end* as **done**.
2. Right after it second `useEffect()` triggers. But if it was subscribed only to images array `length` why does it even start now? The `images.length` was `0` as a default state and was not changed yet. That part I don't understand
3. Then  `fetch()` activates when `useEffect()` was already completed. Thats probably because it has `async` already inside.
4. In the middle of fetching second `useEffect()` triggers again and this time because `images.length` was actually changed.

here is the code:

```
const cardReducer = (state, action) => {
    console.log(state, action)
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'STACK_CARDS':
            return { ...state, images: state.images.concat(action.images) }
        case 'FETCHING_CARDS':
            return { ...state, fetching: action.fetching }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

function App() {
    const classes = useStyles()

    const [
        cardData,
        cardDispatch
    ] = useReducer(cardReducer, { images: [], fetching: true })

    useEffect(
        () => {
            console.log('begin')
            cardDispatch({ type: 'FETCHING_CARDS', fetching: true })
            console.log('post dispatch')

            console.log('fetch url', fetch(`https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=0&limit=2`))

            fetch(`https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=0&limit=2`)
                .then((data) => data.json())
                .then((images) => {
                    console.log('fetch start')  
                    cardDispatch({ type: 'STACK_CARDS', images })
                    cardDispatch({ type: 'FETCHING_CARDS', fetching: false })
                    console.log('fetch ok') 
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    cardDispatch({ type: 'FETCHING_CARDS', fetching: false })
                    console.log('fetch error')  
                    return e
                })

            console.log('end ---')
        },
        [cardDispatch]
    )

    useEffect(
        () => {
            console.log('hooks loading ', cardData.images.length)
        },
        [cardData.images.length]
    )
```

Comment: after the render useEffect calls, React js docs Does useEffect run after every render? Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `useEffects that need to be run are executed in order in which they are written`. This explain the fact that the first useEffect is run and then the second one runs.
- Now `useEffect run on an initial render and whenever a value within their dependency array changes`. This explain the fact that the second useEffect is executed even before the data is available

Now you can control what you do within the useEffect by ignoring the initial render my maintain a ref

```
function App() {
    const classes = useStyles()

    const [
        cardData,
        cardDispatch
    ] = useReducer(cardReducer, { images: [], fetching: true })

    useEffect(
        () => {
            console.log('begin')
            cardDispatch({ type: 'FETCHING_CARDS', fetching: true })
            console.log('post dispatch')

            console.log('fetch url', fetch(`https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=0&limit=2`))

            fetch(`https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=0&limit=2`)
                .then((data) => data.json())
                .then((images) => {
                    console.log('fetch start')  
                    cardDispatch({ type: 'STACK_CARDS', images })
                    cardDispatch({ type: 'FETCHING_CARDS', fetching: false })
                    console.log('fetch ok') 
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    cardDispatch({ type: 'FETCHING_CARDS', fetching: false })
                    console.log('fetch error')  
                    return e
                })

            console.log('end ---')
        },
        [cardDispatch]
    )

    const initialRender = useRef(true);
    useEffect(() => {
         if(!initialRender.current) {
            console.log('hooks loading ', cardData.images.length)

         } else {
            initialRender.current = false;
         }

     },
     [cardData.images.length])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because hook useEfect 
in 1 step don't have values 
and in 2 step coming